# What are the risks of connecting via VNC to an untrusted host?

Tags: client-side, remote-desktop, client

There are questions about connecting to an untrusted host via SSH [[1]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38128/what-are-the-risks-of-sshing-to-an-untrusted-host) [[2]](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/7480/risks-of-ssh-to-an-untrusted-host), [RDP](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/38539/why-would-a-remote-desktop-connection-harm-my-pc/38541), and with [X11 forwarding enabled](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/14815/security-concerns-with-x11-forwarding).

What about when connecting via VNC?  What risks are there to the client?

To be clear: the assumption is that the remote host is under the control of a malicious party and they are actively trying to gain access to your client PC or otherwise gain useful information.

Answer (score 2):

There's a couple of potential risks which spring to mind.

Firstly if there's a vulnerability in the client software (e.g. a buffer overflow) by connecting to a malicious server it could be possible for the server to compromise the client machine via the VNC protocol.

Secondly, there's the obvious risk that the client machine is visible to the server (i.e. the server would know the IP address of the client machine) which may allow it to target the client for other attacks (whether these would succeed would of course depend on the configuration of the client).

The last risk that springs to mind is again kind of obvious which is that any data entered by the client into the VNC session on the server could be observed and modified, so for example by connecting to the malicious server and then using the browser on that server, things like website login credentials may be compromised.

Comment: "Firstly if there's a vulnerability in the client software ". There is. There always is.